# i got an error "No valid host was found" ,when i deploy openstack-rally,and test my cloud.

Tags: python-2.7, openstack, openstack-nova

i got an error as blow,which tells me "No valid host was found",but my compute is ok,and i can create a VM by other way.

```
 GetResourceErrorStatus: Resource <Server: s_rally_a8539dd5_B24CrxN7> has ERROR status.
    Fault: {u'message': u'No valid host was found. Exceeded max scheduling attempts 3 for instance 061027f0-9e08-4f36-8bca-437be4eb1f1f. Last exception: [u\'Traceback (most recent call last):\\n\', u\'  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2329, in _do', u'code': 500, u'created': u'2018-09-12T02:52:15Z'}
```

he is my openrc:

```
unset OS_SERVICE_TOKEN
unset TMOUT
export OS_USERNAME=admin
export OS_PASSWORD=13f24ba768f14d9f
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://10.254.4.3:5000/v2.0
export PS1='[\u@\h \W(keystone_admin)]\$ '
export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=2.0
export OS_TENANT_NAME=admin
export OS_REGION_NAME=RegionOne
export OS_VOLUME_API_VERSION=2
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export OS_COMPUTE_API_VERSION=2
```

the output of rally deployment check as follows:
[root@9bbb1334cda8 ~(keystone_admin)]# rally deployment check

```
keystone endpoints are valid and following services are available:
+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| services    | type         | status    |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| __unknown__ | computev3    | Available |
| __unknown__ | extension    | Available |
| __unknown__ | volumev2     | Available |
| ceilometer  | metering     | Available |
| cinder      | volume       | Available |
| ec2         | ec2          | Available |
| glance      | image        | Available |
| gnocchi     | metric       | Available |
| keystone    | identity     | Available |
| neutron     | network      | Available |
| nova        | compute      | Available |
| s3          | s3           | Available |
| senlin      | clustering   | Available |
| swift       | object-store | Available |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have either have no nova-computes available, or you do not have any free compute resources available.

Basically you have no more space to create Virtual Machines.